# homebrew: ngspice not building (x11.c:29:12: fatal error: 'X11/IntrinsicP.h' file not found and then some)

Tags: homebrew, x11

I'm a homebrew newbie (broob?). Trying to build ngspice I encounter the error described in the title. Before I get into that though, it turns out I actually don't even really want/need X11 support at the moment. I'm such a newbie I don't even know how to tell brew to leave out X. In the formula I see:

option "with-x", "Build with X support"

But if I build "--without-x" I still see the same error. How do you say "not --with-x"?

OK, on to the compile trouble:

I can see the file is really there in the X11 directories:

```
$ find /opt/X11/ -name IntrinsicP.h 
/opt/X11//include/X11/IntrinsicP.h
```

But somehow homebrew is not seeing that include path. What the best way to alert brew to the location of this file? I tried:

```
ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
```

which works, in the sense that the include problem goes away, but it produces a linker problem:

```
ld: library not found for -lXaw
```

Again, I found some Xaw libs in /opt/X11, but I've not sorted out how to educate homebrew enough to actually link to them. ;-(

```
$ find /opt/X11/ -name "*Xaw*" 

/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw/XawImP.h
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw/XawInit.h
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/Xaw3dP.h
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/XawImP.h
/opt/X11//include/X11/Xaw3d/XawInit.h
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.6.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.7.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.8.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw3d.8.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw3d.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw6.6.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw6.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw7.7.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw7.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw8.8.dylib
/opt/X11//lib/libXaw8.dylib
/opt/X11//share/doc/libXaw3d
/opt/X11//share/man/man3/Xaw.3
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

-steve

Comment: You could try to edit the brew formula by using [`brew edit ngspice`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#can-i-edit-formulae-myself), and try to remove/alter the `--with-x` flag.

Comment: If you do want to include extra paths, try setting `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` before running the brew command: `export CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include` and `export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/X11/lib`. I have never tried that myself with brew, but it usually works in a variety of these kind of problems.

Comment: Strange, brew somehow ignores the environment variables apparently.

Comment: It probably uses a subshell of its own, and perhaps then even using `export` may fail. Which is unfortunate, really; it should use environment variables.

Comment: It's a design decision that Homebrew sanitizes the build environment; it makes builds much more reproducible. Steve, can you post the output of brew gist-logs --config --doctor ngspice after a failed build attempt with the Homebrew ngspice.rb? For ngspice, X support should be disabled unless you explicitly enable it, but --without-x is indeed the Homebrew antonym to --with-x.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this. This reflects an inconsistency in ngspice's configure that was not accommodated by the Homebrew formula. ngspice needs --without-x in configure to stop trying to link to X even though it needs --with-x to actually build X support.

This will be fixed once [this pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/32403) is accepted.

Homebrew welcomes these kinds of issues at the Github issue tracker; maintainers don't come around here much. Following the troubleshooting advice that brew recommends ("READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting") will make diagnosing problems easier in any venue. :)

Comment: Cool! So I'll check in with homebrew. I didn't want to pollute the issue tracker with my stupidity, if that was the trouble. ;-)

Comment: Excellent! I updated my brew (brew update) and now I can build without x support. Later I'll worry about building *with* x support. ;-)